# Create a Clone of existing Spatial DB on SQL Server instance

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-pro, sql-server-spatial

I have a spatial database on a SQL Server Instance. I want to create a copy of it in the same instance. I tried the following approaches:

- Backing up the existing XYZ DB and restoring it with a new name XYZ_Clone. Following that, I was able to connect to the XYZ_Clone via SSMS but when I attempted to set up a DB connection to it via ArcMap, I got the following error.[image]

2. Following the error, we found a root cause stating "*have you recently restored your SDE database into another database. If that's the case then there is a conflict between the configuration of SDE generated schema, as it will hold the name of the previous database but your current new database name is Changed.*". So, we edited the number of entries storing the DB name such as

- SDE_column_registry
- SDE_layers
- SDE_raster_columns
- SDE_table_registry

3. That didn't help. So, I deleted the XYZ_Clone and created a new Enterprise Geodatabase through ArcMap 10.3 using the 'Create Enterprise Geodatabase' tool.
4. Then I tried to copy the XYZ DB to XYZ_Clone DB using the instructions given in the following link.
   [Copying a geodatabase](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/copy-a-geodatabase-using-the-extract-data-wizard.htm)

After this, I am getting the error messages that features were not copied as the [Shape] columns were not found.

Is there a straightforward way/process of creating a Spatial DB clone?

Answer (score 0):

I went through a request with ESRI about trying to do this a few years ago.  In the end, the answer was simply:  Don't do it.  The database name is stored in too many places within the database itself, and some of them not search/replaceable (and they wouldn't tell me where, or if there could be any other issues).

In the end, the solution was to export the database to an "XML Workspace Document" (including data, not just schema), and then create a NEW SQL (SDE) database, and then load the XML Workspace Document into that new database.

I also tried creating a script to copy all the datasets, feature classes and tables one by one.  That works, too, but is tedious to implement, and there could be other object types in a database that could be missed.